# How to prevent fragment recreation when selected from NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, navigation-drawer

I have a simple activity in which it's hosted a Navigation Drawer. One of its entry is a WebView, which takes a lot to loads (it displays Gmail, so that following all those nasty redirects takes quite a lot).

I would like to retain the fragment even when different selections occur. I thought that these solutions might work. They didn't.

1) Not re-creating the fragment: even if mWebmailFragment *actually* is **not null**, onCreateView() is called in any case.

```
 private Fragment mWebmailFragment /*, the others */;

 public void selectItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case FRAGMENT_CODE_WEBMAIL:
            mWebmailFragment = mWebmailFragment!=null ? mWebmailFragment : new WebmailFragment();
            fragment = mWebmailFragment;
            break;
     // ...
 }
```

2) if onCreateView() is called, retaining WebView object state may work. Well, it doesn't: debugging I discovered that savedInstanceState is *always* null. I don't know why.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    // Retain instance
    setRetainInstance(true);

    //....

    // SavedState
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    } else {
        // do stuff
    }
}
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}
```

Comment: How do you change fragments when you select another one? if you "replace" them, maybe try "show()" and "hide()" instead.

Comment: Nope... I used the "hide all - show selected" logic, but still when an orientation change occurs everything messes up. As the time being, I solved forcing the UI on portrait mode, but you can understand how much a limit it is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't use hide/Show properly. In your fragment transaction use add() to load the fragment instead of replace().

Change this

```
final FragmentManager myFragmentManger = myContext
                    .getSupportFragmentManager();
            final FragmentTransaction myFragmentTransaction = myFragmentManger
                    .beginTransaction();
            myFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, aFragment,
                    aFragmentTag.getFragment());
```

to

```
final FragmentManager myFragmentManger = myContext
                    .getSupportFragmentManager();
            final FragmentTransaction myFragmentTransaction = myFragmentManger
                    .beginTransaction();
            myFragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content, aFragment,
                    aFragmentTag.getFragment());
```

If you use replace, createview() of fragment will be called everytime. Try to use the add() as above code does.